# Помогите с формой на Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap, форма

Мне нужен код элементарной формы Bootstrap как на картинке, чтобы поле пароля и кнопка были в одной строке:

[image: Форма]

Comment: а вы где взяли эту картинку? Заскринили с какого-то сайта? Если да, то откройте исходный код и скопируйте его

Comment: Это я на обычном html css стряпал за 1 минуту

Comment: а что тогда нужно от бутстрапа? Стили инпутов? Или именно расположение?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/toefkrjv/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я все правильно понял, то к примеру так с помощью гридов

```html
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<form action="" class="form clearfix">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Логин">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-10">
    <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Пароль">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <input class="btn btn-block" type="submit" value="Войти">
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Из примера бутстрапа

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Пароль">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Войти</button>
      </span>
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
```

Если нужно разделить поле от кнопки, тогда как предложил Василий Барабашев

Answer (score 0):

Если необходимо использовать встроенные классы, то можно вот так:

```css
form {
  width: 200px;
}
input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
}
input[type="password"] {
  width: 65%;
}
button {
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<form class="clearfix">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Логин">
  <input class="pull-left" type="password" placeholder="Пароль">
  <button class="pull-right">Войти</button>
</form>
```